# Signing in with instagram with requests, when creating a class with session an AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'headers' is thrown

Tags: python, python-requests, instagram

I am working on a small project that allows users to perform specific actions on their instagram accounts. These actions will be get following/followers, unfollow accounts, and accept follow requests. For some reason, I can't seem to get the signing of an account to work when trying to write a class for it. I have signin working with function, but I want to make the account/session it's own data type so that I can manipulate it for my intended future features. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here is my current code:

```
import requests
import json

class User:

    # Constructor
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.session = requests.Session()
        self.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B143 Safari/601.1'
        self.password = password
        self.username = username
        self.baseUrl = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/'
        self.refererUrl = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/'

    # Methods
    def start_session(self):

        try:
            self.req = self.session.get(self.baseUrl)
            self.session.headers = {'user-agent': self.userAgent}
            self.session.headers.update({'Referer': self.refererUrl})
            self.session.headers.update({'x-csrftoken': self.req.cookies['csrftoken']})
            self.login_data = {'username': self.username, 'password': self.password}
            self.login = self.session.post(self.baseUrl, data=self.login_data, allow_redirects=True)
            self.headers.update({'x-csrftoken': self.login.cookies['csrftoken']})
            print(self.login.json())


        except:
            print("There was an error signing in.")


def main():
    print("Welcome to InstaTool. Please type in your username and password.")
    username = input("Username: ")
    password = input("Password: ")
    insta_account = User(username, password)
    insta_account.start_session()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ty/InstaTool/InstaTool.py", line 50, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/ty/InstaTool/InstaTool.py", line 46, in main
    insta_account.start_session()
  File "/Users/ty/InstaTool/InstaTool.py", line 33, in start_session
    self.headers.update({'x-csrftoken': self.login.cookies['csrftoken']})
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'headers'
```

I'm confused because I'm not sure why my object would need an 'headers' attribute if I plan on updating the headers in the start_session() function. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `headers` method is tried to be called on `self`, which is `User`:

```
self.headers.update({'x-csrftoken': self.login.cookies['csrftoken']})
```

You probably wanted this line to be:

```
self.session.headers.update({'x-csrftoken': self.login.cookies['csrftoken']})
```

Comment: Opps didn't catch that mistake. Thanks for the help though!